# calling an array in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

so….I have a function in my model which calls the last element of a table, then I assign the result to a variable and I return it to the controller, the problem is that I can't access the array. I need the "id".

```
// model
function ultimo()
{
    $result = $this->db->select('*')->order_by("id","desc")->get('articulos', 1)->result();
    return $result;
}
//controller
$ultimo['id']=$this->mod_articulos->ultimo();

// I try to access the array like this: (for test purposes)
// this gives me an array:
echo "<br /><br />Valor de Datos: ".$ultimo['id'];

// content of the array:
array(1) 
{ 
    ["id"]=> array(1) 
    { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#25 (13) 
        { 
            ["id"]=>          string(2) "15" 
            ["familia"]=>     string(2) "01" 
            ["subfamilia"]=>  string(2) "01" 
            ["codigo"]=>      string(2) "03" 
            ["cod_barras"]=>  string(1) "3" 
            ["nombre"]=>      string(22) "Aceite de Oliva Virgen" 
            ["descripcion"]=> string(20) "en botellas de 500ml" 
            ["pcp"]=>         string(4) "6.00" 
            ["pvp"]=>         string(5) "25.00" 
            ["proveedor"]=>   string(2) "03" 
            ["stock"]=>       string(6) "120000" 
            ["minstock"]=>    string(4) "1000" 
            ["imagen"]=>      string(0) "" 
        }
    }
}
```

if I use     `$ultimo['id']->id;` I get the non-object error. Any advice will be more than welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to use:

```
$ultimo['id'][0]->id;
```

Comment: @Alejandro If this answered your question you should mark it as approved.  This helps your acceptance rating, which will make others more likely to help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`$ultimo['id']` is an array, so this is what you will do

```
foreach($ultimo['id'] as $obj){
   echo "Valor de Datos: ".$obj->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should do:

```
$ultimo = $this->mod_articulos->ultimo();

if ($ultimo) // if array not empty
{
    echo $ultimo[0]->id;
}
```

Simply remember the CI's `result()` method returns an array of rows, just like SQL.